# Difference between putting a break point and calling DebugBreak()

Tags: debugging

Does anyone know what's the difference between using breakpoints and calling DebugBreak() func. for example in windows platforms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious difference is that putting a breakpoint in is an interactive process - it has to be done manually (by each developer who wants to break at a certain point). This is flexible, but manual.

On the other hand, as `DebugBreak` is *programmatic*, it means that it affects *all* developers who run through that code (which may be appropriate if you always want developers to stop at that point as it means something's *about* to go wrong, for example) - but you won't be able to add breakpoints as flexibly while the code is executing.

Use each technique in its place - personally I don't use programmatically-forced break points very often at all.

Comment: Thanks. that was what I thought at first hand. But I was not sure if there were any functional difference btw. these too.